# What to do when pytesseract seems to work but is not?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am creating an app that creates an organized, digital schedule out of a picture of one ([actual sample photo](https://tinypic.host/image/sample-06-Copy.QHFIM)).

I am using python v 3.12.0, vscode, and the jupyter extension on vsc.
I installed pytesseract and pillow on my pc, and am sure there are no path issues there.

Here is the full python code:

```
import os, sys
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

im = Image.open("sample_06.jpeg")

#psm 4 is for columns, spreadsheets
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config = "--psm 4")

print(text)
```

When I run the code, it shows there are no problems (exited with code=0), but the text is never printed.
I have been able to use other methods with the image, too, like `print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)` with success.

Additionally, I get this error message when running the code sometimes:
`cannot convert --f=c:\Users\{myUserName}\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-9652HMb7WtRUPRAm.json`
and putting that into a search engine does not yield much.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is there something more direct and simpler you can use pytessaract with? Like putting a file to try and use it on in your working directory so you rule out paths. Use the demo stuff the quick start includes, etc..You only see that error sometime?

Comment: A full error message might help us help you.  But that `.json` filename looks like one that the jupyter server uses to setup the browser session  It passed via the `sys.argv` list.  We see something like this when people try to use a `argparse` commandline parse in a notebook session.

Comment: Here an SO with a similar `--f=...json` message when trying to parse `sys.argv` in a `notebook`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513233/unrecognized-arguments-exception-when-importing-from-python-script-in-jupyter-no.  Something in your `pytesseract` usage is designed for script usage, not notebook.

Comment: `tesseract - psm 4` used for: Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.